# Probabilities of Orbiting Particles Appearing Within a Bounded Area

Tags: probability

Consider an orbital plane containing three particles. The particles start a random distance from each other and orbit about the center in any arbitrary direction at three different RPM.

What is the probability that all three particles are within an area bounded by (a,b,c,d) before one particle completes 1 revolution, 2 revolutions, 3 revolutions?

**Life Application:**

I'm walking on a track that is one mile in circumference. If there are two other people walking or running, my experience is that 80% of the time, before I complete 2 revolutions, I come within 10 feet of both the others at the same time and was wondering how to explain this.

[image: Three particles in orbital plane]

Comment: I think you need more limits. If one is quite slow relative to the others moving *much* faster, it is far more likely that they will all be together, even in one orbit of the slowest. OTOH if their relative speeds are close, it is far less likely to happen even in many orbits.

Comment: ...for example if the initial condition has **a** (slightly faster than **b**) just ahead of the zone that **b** is in; and **c** (slightly slower than **b**) just behind the zone that **b** is in, it could take many orbits for them to meet in the same zone. And if any two of them have the same speed, they will never be any closer, or further apart.